# SQL TRIGGER: How do you restrict something from being changed?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, database-trigger

In my trigger, I have to restrict column X to change to the value Y, if column Z is of value W. How the IF statement would look? Thank you!

This is the `Class` table:

```
class         type  tara            nr_arme diametru_tun    deplasament
Ticonderoga   cr    Norvegia        16      23              4500
Maryland      vl    SUA             10      12              10000
Foxtrot       vl    Russia          20      45              5800
Buyan         cr    Russia          15      20              15000
Amphion       cr    Marea Britanie  13      14              12000
```

Those are the `ships`:

```
name    class        anul_lansarii
Nava1   Ticonderoga  1995
Nava2   Amphion      1980
Nava3   Foxtrot      2005
Nava4   Buyan        1960
Nava5   Maryland     1970
```

This is the `Consequences` table.

```
name    batalie                 result
Nava1   Battle of Chemulpo Bay  scufundat
Nava3   Battle of Chemulpo Bay  avariat
Nava2   Battle of Hudson Bay    nevatamat
Nava4   Battle of Bengal Bay    nevatamat
Nava5   Battle of Bengal Bay    avariat
```

So if the ship (nava) is of type 'cr', the result cannot be 'nevatamat'. It ignores the update.

Comment: What do you like to get if someone tries to change column X to change to the value Y, if column Z is of value W? An exception or silently ignore the update?

Comment: Ignore the update

Comment: try writing the logic out in english...or even in plsql, then we can better answer your question. if you wanted to include your table definition some example data, even better

Comment: Ignore the entire update statement or just the update on column X?

Comment: I have updated the question, now it should be clearer. Wernfried Domscheit, I don't know how to answer, because the question on the homework is somewhat vague.

Comment: You have three tables which is completely different to "restrict column X to change to the value Y, if column Z is of value W" Also "restrict column X to change" is different to "the result cannot be 'nevatamat'" Please clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test case:

```
SQL> create table class
  2    (class   varchar2(20),
  3     type    varchar2(2));

Table created.

SQL> create table ships
  2    (name    varchar2(5),
  3     class   varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create table consequences
  2    (name    varchar2(5),
  3     result  varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert all
  2    into class values ('Ticonderoga' , 'cr')
  3    into class values ('Maryland'    , 'vl')
  4    --
  5    into ships values ('Nava1'       , 'Ticonderoga')
  6    into ships values ('Nava5'       , 'Maryland')
  7    --
  8    into consequences values ('Nava1', 'scufundat')
  9    into consequences values ('Nava5', 'avariat')
 10  select * from dual;

6 rows created.

SQL>
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_biu_cons
  2    before insert or update on consequences
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    l_type class.type%type;
  6  begin
  7    if :new.result = 'nevatamat' then
  8       select c.type
  9         into l_type
 10         from class c
 11         where c.class = (select s.class
 12                          from ships s
 13                          where s.name = :new.name
 14                         );
 15       if l_type = 'cr' then
 16          raise_application_error(-20000, 'Ship''s type is CR; result can''t be NEVATAMAT');
 17       end if;
 18    end if;
 19  end;
 20  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> update consequences set result = 'nevatamat' where name = 'Nava1';
update consequences set result = 'nevatamat' where name = 'Nava1'
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Ship's type is CR; result can't be NEVATAMAT
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_BIU_CONS", line 13
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_BIU_CONS'


SQL> update consequences set result = 'avariat'   where name = 'Nava1';

1 row updated.

SQL> update consequences set result = 'nevatamat' where name = 'Nava5';

1 row updated.

SQL>
```

Comment: What do you declare here:   l_type class.type%type;   I don't understand

Comment: It is a local variable which is used to accept ship's type ("cr" or "vl" or whichever type you might have). That's the syntax - `table_name.column_name%type`. Your table name is `class`, column name is `type` so it becomes `class.type%type`. I could have used e.g. `l_type varchar2(2)`, but - if you ever decide to modify it, you'll have to modify it all around your code. Referencing column's type is, therefore, a better option.